# why setInterval function run 10s fast compared to current server time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Today i am getting not catchable issue by me because i am not getting error.

I am using setInterval() and created a server based countdown in php....

```
setInterval(gettimeleft,1000);

function gettimeleft(){


        var ctime=$("#time").html();            
        //var ndtime=$("#nextdraw1").html();            
        var ndtime=$("#nextDrawDateTime").val();

        if(ndtime==''|| ndtime=='undefined'){
            getnextdraw();
            return false;
        }

        var datastring='ctime='+ctime+'&ndtime='+ndtime+'&getlefttime=1';
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "test/function.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var a = data;
                //alert(a);
                if(data=='0 : 0 : 0'){                        
                    $("#nextDrawDateTime").val('');
                    var time=$("#nextdraw1").html();
                    var date=$("#date").val();

                    getresult(time,date);
                    getnextdraw();
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('timeleft').innerHTML=data;
                    getontimedraw();
                    var time=$("#ontimevalue").val();
                    var date=$("#ontimedatevalue").val();
                    getresult1(time,date);

                }

            },
            error: function ()
            { console.log('there is some error'); }
        });                         

    }
```

Everything in this code is working fine and countdown also working but only countdown running 10 second faster than current time. Why is this happen and this 10 second is continues.

This same code work fine in my XAMPP Server localhost

How can i set to run according to current time

Comment: I would suggest to set one timestamp in PHP where the countdown should end and then get this timestamp once in JS with AJAX and then count in JS. It's a lot more efficient and there would be no error

Comment: This is because your server and your local machine may always have a slight difference in time - this is normal behaviour.

Comment: @Steve i am not talking about my local server i am talking about my hosting server timing... i have mentioned in above question in last paragraph

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my question @Eykhs. I am using this one date_default_timezone_set("asia/kolkata"); so i think it's fine but issue is same. Could you explain something about end timestamp..